API request using Axios to Reed API keep getting unauthorized 401 code
Here is my code that I'm using on JS
const keywords = "keywords="+ req.body.keyword+"&";
const locationName = "locationName="+req.body.location;
try {
    const result = await axios.get(API_URL + keywords + locationName,{ 
        auth:{ username: API_KEY,
            password:""
        } 
        });
 //Unsure how to send big long query prams 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.results));
    res.render("index.ejs", { content: JSON.stringify(result.data)});
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error.code);
    res.render("index.ejs",{ contnet: JSON.stringify(error)});
} 

});
This is the code I'm running in the hopes to get a response from Reeds API.
But I keep getting 401 error code.
On the docs it says: You will need to include your api key for all requests in a basic authentication http header as the username, leaving the password empty.
https://www.reed.co.uk/developers/Jobseeker
Here's the weird part which I can't understand. I can use this same API call on postman and I get the response that I want but for some reason I can't get it when I run on a local host.
